# Yet another LFI issue

Tags: javascript, php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ship Parts</title>
        <script src="libs/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/styles/boot2016.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/styles/cyber.css">
        <script src="libs/scripts/common1.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/scripts/cyberO.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
        <div class="container" style="margin-bottom:60px;">
                <div style="background-image:url('libs/images/ocean.jpg'); background-position: center; padding: 40px; font-size:72px; color:white;" class="text-center align-middle" >
                        <h1>Ship-Parts Military Boats</h1>
                </div>
                <h2>Welcome to Ship-Parts Military Boats</h2>
                <p>Ship-Parts Military Boats are high-performance rigid hull inflatable boats and vessels that are specifically designed for the extreme endurance needs of the military and law enforcement.</p>

                <p><strong>Select a product:</strong></p>
                <form action="index.php" method="POST" id="products">
                        <select name="product">
                                <option value="inflatable.html">Inflatable Boats</option>
                                <option value="navy.html">Navy Boats</option>
                                <option value="coastguard.html">Coast Guard Boats</option>
                                <option value="lawenforcement.html">Law Enforcement Boats</option>
                                <option value="about.html">About Us</option>
                        </select>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" value="Show Info" />
                </form>
                <br>

                <?php
                        if(isset($_POST["product"]) ) {
                                include $_POST["product"];
                        }
                        else {
                                include "about.html";
                        }

                ?>


        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So I'm supposed to fix this website. I need to verify that the options that the optionvalue's point to are the ones they're supposed to be before the page sends that information through, so that even if someone changes the file from `inflatables.html` to `allmyloginsxd.html` it'll just show up as an error.

I don't understand a thing about code (and the course I'm taking won't teach me or give me time to learn) so the simpler you can explain everything to me the better.

Comment: '*and the course I'm taking won't teach me or give me time to learn*' - In which case, you drop it and find a more suitable teacher / course.

Comment: If you do it before the page sends the data, one can assume it needs to be done in JavaScript, I would advise that you have server side checks too.

Answer (score 0):

As advised in my comment, consider using server side checks along side your client side validation to ensure that you have a backup in the instance that your client side validation is bypassed.

Simply put, you can use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check the input of the options:

```
/** Your page names would go in here. **/
$correct_values = ['option-val-one', 'option-val-two'];

if (!in_array($_POST['product'], $correct_values)) {
    /** Unknown value has been passed. **/
}
```

Other than that, you have an error in your markup where you have duplicate tags (`</select>`).